# es6 import doesnt notice file change

Tags: node.js, import, discord.js, es6-modules

I'm currently programming a discord bot in module type, and the problem with the reload command is that the import doesn't notice the file changes.

Folder structure (only what relevant)

```
application
├── src
│   ├── handlers
│   │   └── commands.js
│   └── commands
│       └── reload.js
```

commands.js

```
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';

async function reloadCommands(client) {
    await client.commands.clear();
    await client.aliases.clear();
    const commandFiles = readdirSync('./src/commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (let i = 0; i < commandFiles.length; i++) {
        const cmd = await import(`../commands/${commandFiles[i]}`);
        await client.commands.set(cmd.default.name, cmd.default);
        console.log(`[COMMAND] Reloaded ${commandFiles[i]} with command ${cmd.default.name}${cmd.default.aliases}`);

        if (cmd.default.aliases) {
            cmd.default.aliases.forEach(async (alias)  => {
                await client.aliases.set(alias, cmd.default);
            });
        }
    }
    return commandFiles.length;
}

export default { loadCommands, reloadCommands };
```

reload.js

```
import commandHandler from '../handlers/commands.js';

export default {
    name: 'reload',
    description: 'Reloads all commands',
    aliases: ['rl'],

    async execute(message, args, client) {
        try {
            let cmd = await commandHandler.reloadCommands(client);
            message.reply(`${cmd} commands have been reloaded!`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
};
```

Node v18.9.0

I googled but found nothing that helps me

Comment: If you're relying in `import` to reload a changed file, it won't do it.  `import` caches the first one it loads and will use the cached file from then on.  If you want to manually reload a changed file, you will have to use something like `fs.readFile()`, put it in an appropriate wrapper and then `eval()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for me, if I import the commands with searchParams the cache is not used.

No idea if this causes any memory leaks

```
const cmd = await import(`../commands/${commandFiles[i]}?${Date.now()}`);
await client.commands.set(cmd.default.name, cmd.default);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `loadCommands` is defined, but I would personally reapproach the way I wrote the function for reloading commands.

```js
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';

async function reloadCommands(client)
{
    const commandFolders = readdirSync('./commands');

    for (const folder of commandFolders)
    {
        const commandFiles = readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for (const file of commandFiles)
        {
            const command = require
            (`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);

            console.log(`Command ${command.name} loaded!`);
        }
    }

    console.log('All commands loaded!');
}

export default { loadCommands, reloadCommands }
```

And the approach I would take for reload.js

```js
import commandHandler from './handlers/commands.js';

export default {
    name: 'reload',
    description: 'Reloads all commands',
    async execute(message, args)
    {
        if (message.author.id !== 'your id')
        {
            return message.channel.send('You don\'t have permission to use this command!');
        }

        await commandHandler.reloadCommands(message.client);

        message.channel.send('All commands reloaded!');
    }
}
```

Try seeing if there's a difference between this and the other.